# KARATE UI: How to pass a dynamic value to a locator and assertions?

Tags: user-interface, karate

Api returns a confirmationNumber, which i'm storing in a variable then using that confirmationNumber to click and assert on the UI page.

- def myFeature = call read('Feature1.feature')
- def confirmationNumber = myFeature.confirmationNumber

//some ui login steps are here

Then input('#paymentNum',confirmationNumber)  //--successfully entered confirmationNumber

And assert exists('{div}confirmationNumber'). //--not successful. not able to read the stored value

And click('{a}confirmationNumber')  //--not successful. not able to read the stored value

Please help
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy. Think of anything within the `(` and `)` as pure JavaScript. Also please note the extra `exists`, hmm maybe I should re-design that part of the API - and thanks for asking this question ! https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1148

```
# this is how to use exists() right now, but I have decided to change this !
And assert exists('{div}' + confirmationNumber).exists
And click('{a}' + confirmationNumber)
```

Comment: Thank you Peter very much for quick response. I've spent 3 days on this... resolved now